# Error downloading Node.js during Maven build with frontend-maven-plugin

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, maven

I am encountering an issue while building my Spring Boot application using Maven. The build process is attempting to download Node.js, but it's trying to fetch a version that doesn't seem to exist. Here's the error message:

```
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.10.0:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ sample_system ---
[INFO] Node v18.19.0 was installed, but we need version v12.22.12
[INFO] Installing node version v12.22.12
[INFO] Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.22.12/node-v12.22.12-darwin-arm64.tar.gz to /Users/my_home/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/node/12.22.12/node-12.22.12-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
[INFO] No proxies configured
[INFO] No proxy was configured, downloading directly
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.10.0:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project sia: Could not download Node.js: Got error code 404 from the server. -> [Help 1]
```

I am using the frontend-maven-plugin version 1.10.0.

It is trying to download Node.js version v12.22.12 for macOS arm64 architecture.
I am on a MacBook Pro, Apple M1 Pro Chipset with Ventura 13.6.2.

The download fails because the specified file (node-v12.22.12-darwin-arm64.tar.gz) does not exist on the server.

Why is the build trying to download a Node.js version that doesn't exist?

Is there a way to configure the frontend-maven-plugin to download a different Node.js version or file?